# HP laptop: when I close the lid the screen locks. How do I disable this behavior?

Tags: lock-screen

I went to Settings>Privacy. It says
Screen Lock Off

How can that be? If I close the laptop and then open it again, I find a screen showing the date/time in big characters. Then I press the Esc key and now the system prompts me to enter a password (by the way it does not say if it is the root password or the regular user password; I tried with both but it rejects both!). And it shows a button with 'Unlock' written on it! So it has locked the screen despite the fact that Settings>Privacy says Screen Lock Off.

EDIT: This is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but screen lock is the automatic locking when you are idle for X amount of minutes, isn't it?

Comment: Well, yes, but I have already disable that behavior (I don't remember how).

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Settings>Privacy>Screen Lock window in your question. it looks like you may have tried the answers posted so far.

Comment: I 'll use the Answer Your Question button to send the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Open your settings dialog - select "Privacy" on the left side, then "Screen Lock"
[image]

Now turn off the "Automatic Screen lock" and "Lock Screen on suspend"

Turning off both worked with my hardware.

Comment: Automatic Screen Lock is off. But I don't have a Lock Screen on Suspend.

Comment: I do have Power>Suspend & Power Button>Automatic Suspend which is off.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am using elementaryOS Hera 5.1 which is built off of Ubuntu, so I am not sure if your settings will be identical, but as you can see I have an option that says `when lid is closed: suspend` which when I enter the administrative password, I can set to do whatever I want. This was in System Settings > Power. If you do not have this setting let me know.

Comment: No, I don't have that setting.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image_1]
This is a screenshot. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx